# Blogger doesn't resize my blog to fit smaller monitors

Tags: javascript, css, blogger

My blog looks great on a standard 20 inch monitor or larger, but if I drag it to my laptop... I have a scroll bar and it's just large and bulky. What seems to be the problem? If I re-size the blog then it destroys it because everything; even the youtube video stays the same.

Any help would be very appreciated!

http://skepticsoup.com < - Blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In ur css code u have mentioned width as 1500px. make it as 100%


body {
min-width: 1500px;
}
.content-outer, .content-fauxcolumn-outer, .region-inner {
min-width: 1500px;
max-width: 1500px;
_width: 1500px;
}
.main-inner .columns {
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 500px;
}
```

Comment: I can only find this with 1500, but how do I convert the others? Would I really convert them using the standard algebraic formula? lol Thanks. 


<b:template-skin>
      <b:variable default='960px' name='content.width' type='length' value='1500px'/>
      <b:variable default='0' name='main.column.left.width' type='length' value='0px'/>
      <b:variable default='310px' name='main.column.right.width' type='length' value='500px'/>

Comment: try to make it 100%. there is one <style> block at the end of head element.change that first and see what output you are getting.

Comment: when I Ctrl+F for <style> it finds absolutely nothing. Could this be my issue? Do I need to add css?

Comment: where you are doing Ctrl+f ? open your page. go to source and then do it. search <style id='template-skin-1' type='text/css'>

Comment: i would rather suggest you to rightclick the browser and go to source and find it.

Comment: well yea but that's the only way you can edit the template with HTML/CSS. I can use a widget, but that's all I have.

Comment: check your source first. and find the style element. then you can edit that.

Comment: Ah, thank you :) I get it now lol. It was content.width and I had to replace it. I appreciate your help bro!